# Stored procedure does not update the table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

I want a stored procedure to calculate the age from the birthdate.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateAge
AS
    UPDATE Person
    SET Age = DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), BirthDate) 
    WHERE Age = Null;
```

Here is my table 'Person'

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BirthDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [Lastname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Firstname] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Age] [nchar](10) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

However when I execute the procedure, table with 'Person' does not change. It does not fill the column with Age...

What might be the problem?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Are you actually calling the stored procedure?

Comment: OT why is Age declared as nchar instead of int?

Comment: In fact not even `int` - `tinyint` is the correct data type unless you happen to be Sub-zero from Mortal Kombat :)

Comment: `Age` should be a computed column, otherwise you will constantly need to update it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious problem is:

```
UPDATE Person
    SET Age = DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), BirthDate)
    WHERE Age = Null;
    ----------^
```

The equality always evaluates to `NULL` (even when `age` is `NULL`).  And `WHERE` clauses filter out `NULL` results.  That part can be fixed using:

```
UPDATE Person
    SET Age = DATEDIFF(year, GETDATE(), BirthDate)
    WHERE Age IS Null;
```

You will next find that all the ages are negative, but that is the code you have included.  Assuming that `BirthDate`s are in the past, you want the arguments in the opposite order.

Your `CREATE TABLE` also doesn't work, because the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is not correct.  However, the table seems to exist, so I assume that is a transcription error in writing the question.